# Spring Boot - Externalized properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot project that builds an executable war and is configured with an `application.properties` file and a `application-dev.properties` in `src/main/resources`.

The first line in the `application.properties` is `spring.profiles.active=dev`, which triggers the inclusion of `application-dev.properties` when running as expected.

My problem is that I can't seem to override these properties with an external properties source (after everything is jarred / warred up). For simple debugging, I've created a file `settings.properties` in the root of my project, and specified `spring.profiles.active=dev,deploy` in it hoping to also trigger the "deploy" profile.

However, when I run the following:

`java -jar target/project-0.1.0-LOCAL-NA.war --spring.config.location=file:./settings.properties`

the deploy profile is never enabled. I thought I had this working with a previous version (running 1.1.6.RELEASE now, coming from 1.0.2.RELEASE) but rolling back didn't help either.

Am I missing something obvious?

## Update 1:

So while debugging I discovered that `Environment.getActiveProfiles()` will only return 1 item, even if there's multiple active profiles (dev & deploy in this case). So, while my reporting was only listing dev, deploy was there also.

I've got things running again by using environment variables rather than properties files for profiles, but I'd like to get everything setup with just the files...

Comment: Also, I've tried it with `--spring.config.location=settings.properties` as well, with no luck

Comment: Is that `settings.properties` file actually in the directory you're running `java` from, or is it in the classpath?

Comment: Yes. It's in the root of the project next to the pom.xml

Comment: What happens if you use an absolute filename, either with `file:///` or starting with `\`?

Comment: How about calling the external config `application.properties` and putting it inside a `/config` directory that is in same path as the jar? Then Spring Boot will automatically use that file with higher precedence that the properties files inside the jar

Comment: No dice on either :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem that you've described. Both `./config/application.properties` and a file pointed to by `--spring.config.location` override the jar's `application.properties` file. Can you please share a simple project that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry to waste your time but it turns out it was totally unrelated to properties. Answer posted below for the curious.

Thanks for the willingness to help!

Answer (score 1):

When starting up with a jar file we discovered that you can't use "-D" to inject system variables. You have to use "--".

this worked for us assuming you coded your app to use profiles

```
    java -jar myapplication.jar
    --spring.profiles.active=override
    --spring.config.location=file:/path/to/file/application-override.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

It's embarrassing, but I've got to own up to it: I totally misread the results I was dealing with.

`--spring.config.location=settings.properties` was indeed working properly. I had a combination of a logging issue & a mismatched dependency version that made things appear as if properties were not being properly populated.

#### FWIW

It turns out Logback interpolates the following

`log.info("Profiles: {}", profileArray)`

(where the array is `[dev, deploy]`) as `Profiles: dev` -- basically only showing the first element in the array.  Adjusting my logging to:

`log.info("Profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(profileArray) )`

lead me to figure out the other issue quickly.