# Spring Boot Externalizing properties not working

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, properties, spring-boot

I have looked at the below threads and followed things given there. Still my property override is not happening

1. [Spring Boot - Externalized properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963919/spring-boot-externalized-properties)
2. [Profile Specific Property Enablement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662381/issue-overriding-application-properties-in-spring-boot-profile-specific-applic)
3. [Spring Boot External Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870785/spring-boot-external-config)

I am on Tomcat 8.0.33 and Spring boot starter web and got this in my setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog.level=INFO -Dspring.config.location=file:/opt/jboss/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/overrides/ -Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

And in the overrides folder I got 2 files

1) `application.properties`
2)  `application-dev.properties`

The application.properties has a single entry in it

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

I see that the proper log.level is fed to my code which means this command is working. Its just that I am clueless as to why my override is not happening as expected

I don't have any `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer code in my workspace. I am not even sure if I need 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use this method to externalise properties. First, I'll try a suggestion for your method and then I'll show you what I'm using.

The suggestion for your method is to use file:/// instead of file:/ as with Spring I found that when not passing the three slashes after the colon it didn't recognise the property.

I've created a sample project for you, [available here with instructions](http://devopsfolks.com/stackoverflow-material/#36635163).

Now for the method I use.

I define a Configuration file for each profile and I keep the application.properties file under src/main/resources.

Then I use the @Profile and @PropertySource annotations on each configuration file.

For example:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.devopsbuddy/application-dev.properties")
public class DevelopmentConfig {

@Bean
public EmailService emailService() {
    return new MockEmailService();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean h2ConsoleServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
    bean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
    return bean;
}
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.devopsbuddy/application-prod.properties")
public class ProductionConfig {

@Bean
public EmailService emailService() {
    return new SmtpEmailService();
}
}
```

I have also got a Configuration file that is valid for all profiles, which I call ApplicationConfig, as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.devopsbuddy.backend.persistence.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.devopsbuddy.backend.persistence.domain.backend")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.devopsbuddy/application-common.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

My src/main/resources/application.properties file looks like the following:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
default.to.address=me@example.com
token.expiration.length.minutes=120
```

Of course I could externalise the spring.profile.active property by passing it as a system property but for my case and for now it's fine.

When running the application, if I pass the "dev" profile, Spring will load all properties and Beans defined in the DevelopmentConfig class plus all those in ApplicationConfig. If I pass "prod", the ProductionConfig and ApplicationConfig properties will be loaded instead.

I'm completing a course on how to create a Spring Boot website with Security, Email, Data JPA, Amazon Web Services, Stripe and much more. If you want, you can register your interest [here](http://academy.devopsfolks.com/courses/startup-ready-web-skeleton-with-spring-boot-aws-and-stripe) and you will get notified when the course is open for enrolment.

Comment: Hi Shiv, I've updated my answer with a link to a sample project that demonstrates the above. For your reference, you can find the sample project here. http://devopsfolks.com/stackoverflow-material/#36635163

Comment: Thank You. @Marco. Your example worked like a charm. I love you. I marked your answer as accepted

Comment: I got a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034785/spring-boot-custom-error-controller-returning-empty-json-response. Please help if possible