# Environment specific application.properties in springboot Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm trying to automate the process of deploying code using github and jenkins job to deploy my Springboot Application on AWS .

I want to know where should I place the application.properties file in case I m deploying a war file on Tomcat and don't want this file to be pushed onto github as it may contain some database credentials , not to be exposed.

Should I put separate application-prod.properties file in Tomcat (AWS) so that my war file will be independent of these properties ?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635163/spring-boot-externalizing-properties-not-working/36635367#36635367).

In a nutshell, you externalise the properties and then pass one or more profiles that will activate one or more Spring Configuration classes. Each Configuration class will load one or more property file. In your case, if you only have one environment, you can just create a configuration file for one profile.

Then, on your AWS instance, you will deploy the configuration file separately. At runtime, you will need to pass to your Spring Boot application the active profile(s). You can do this by passing the VM argument: -Dspring.profiles.active=[your-profile]

I'm completing the final lectures on an online course that shows how to create from scratch a Spring Boot website with Thymeleaf, Spring Security, Email and Data JPA, how to process credit card payments with Stripe and how to deploy to AWS. You can register your interest [here](http://academy.devopsfolks.com/courses/startup-ready-web-skeleton-with-spring-boot-aws-and-stripe).

Comment: The link is broken , can't reach the site.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed it now

Comment: using jenkins to build the war using the code from github , don't u think it will require the application.properties file to be present on the github repo ? If not , where should I place the prod specific application.properties in tomcat (in aws) so that the application can use it ?

Comment: There are at least a couple of ways that you can do this. You could place it in S3, protected, and have the EC2 instance where you are deploying your application to download it from there and place it in an external location. You could encrypt the credentials, store it in github and have something on the EC2 instance that decrypts it. If you go for the S3 option, make sure that you assign the S3 role to the EC2 instance and that you don't store any AWS private keys on that box

Answer (score 1):

how about using [`spring-cloud-starter-config`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver) instead of local properties ?

If using `spring-cloud-start-config`, all configurations should be loaded from your `config-center` instead of reading them locally.

Even if you have multiple different environments, `spring-cloud-starter-config` could handle it with different `profiles`.

What's more, `spring-cloud-starter-config` could use local `environment` variables too.

By the way, the only local resource could be `bootstrap.yml` if you are using `spring-cloud-starter-config`.

Wish I can help you!