# Reading From Dynamically Updated Application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I have application properties file which I am dynamically updating using maven build step.

> mvn clean -Dusername=user1 -Durl=xxxx -Dpassword=xxxx -DskipTests
>   install

```
jdbc.url=${url}
jdbc.username=${username}
jdbc.password=${password}
```

I am reading these properties in the configuration class

```
@Configuration 
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-beans.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

  @Value("${jdbc.url}")
  private String url;

 @Value("${jdbc.username}")
  private String username;

 @Value("${jdbc.password}")
 private String password;

@Bean(name = "c3p0DataSource")
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException, 
IOException {

logger.info("Creating Datasource for {}",System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL"));
// logger.info("Creating Datasource for username {}", 
prop.getProperty("username"));
logger.info("Creating Datasource for {}", System.getenv("username"));
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

logger.info("User Name :" + username);//returning $username instead of user1

logger.info("password :" + password);

System.out.println("User name : " + username);

dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
dataSource.setUser(username);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
return dataSource;  }   }
```

I am not getting updated values instead I am getting $username, $password as values, can anyone help me what i am missing here ?

my modified properties file look like below

```
jdbc.url=xxxx
jdbc.username=user1
jdbc.password=xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

you should run

```
mvn clean -Djdbc.username=user1 -Djdbc.url=xxxx -Djdbc.password=xxxx -DskipTests install
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Spring's application property , I will suggest you to use another property file, store it on file system and use org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration class to load values from this file.

org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration has capability to reload property file on change.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html

If you are using maven add below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'dynamically updated' it seems to me you just mean updated at build time and not at runtime. If so then [you need to use the maven resources plugin, define the maven variables and use a different syntax in the properties file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703499/using-maven-properties-in-application-properties-in-spring-boot) This is c[overed in the properties and configuration section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) of the spring boot documentation

Comment: I am doing it in build time only
using the resources as you said
the updated jar contains modified properties file but still not able to read

Comment: Could you either update the question or provide a gist or link to code as the question currently doesn't match the example in the docs?

Comment: Updated question hope it helps

Comment: Could you add the sections from your pom that configure the Maven resources plugin? And the definition of the properties in the properties section of the Pom? Also are you not using the @ syntax like the docs?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826025/cant-access-maven-properties-with-spring?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have tried initialising data manually, which works. You can also give it a try.

You can try out the code below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Configuration;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private Properties properties = new Properties();
    public static String driverClass;
    public static String dataSourceUrl;
    public static String dataSourceUser;
    public static String dataSourcePassword;

    public ApplicationConfiguration() throws IOException {
        properties.load(new InputStreamReader(ApplicationConfiguration.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")));    
        driverClass = properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name");
        dataSourceUrl = properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
        dataSourceUser = properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
        dataSourcePassword = properties.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");
  }

  // Other Code Details

}
```

Now I can easily use it like: `ApplicationConfiguration.driverClass` or `ApplicationConfiguration.dataSourceUser`.

Few other resources are also used by me from application.properties which I am not initialising manually and also not required while `building jar`. So only I am using `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` to use other resources without initialising manually.

Try it once, It may help you :)