# Adding properties to Spring Boot application.yml file at the maven build time

Tags: maven, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have the use case in which I need to write some properties to the spring boot application.yml file for each Spring boot profile at the maven build time.

Input(application.yml) :

```
spring:
  profiles: ED

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    availabilityZones:
      us-west-2: us-west-2a,us-west-2b
    serviceUrl:
      us-west-2a: http://regdiscovery:${eureka.environment}@memeboot-regdiscovery1-ed.aord.expertcity.com:8080/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: RC

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    availabilityZones:
      us-west-2: us-west-2a,us-west-2b
    serviceUrl:
      us-west-2a: http://regdiscovery:${eureka.environment}@memeboot-regdiscovery1-rc.aord.expertcity.com:8080/eureka/
```

Expected output(application.yml after maven build):

```
spring:
  profiles: ED

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    availabilityZones:
      us-west-2: us-west-2a,us-west-2b
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: dummy-url-1,dummy-url-2
      us-west-2a: http://regdiscovery:${eureka.environment}@memeboot-regdiscovery1-ed.aord.expertcity.com:8080/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: RC

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    availabilityZones:
      us-west-2: us-west-2a,us-west-2b
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: dummy-url-1,dummy-url-2
      us-west-2a: http://regdiscovery:${eureka.environment}@memeboot-regdiscovery1-rc.aord.expertcity.com:8080/eureka/
```

Please notice the added line `defaultZone: dummy-url-1,dummy-url-2` in the expected output. Is there any maven plugin available to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you considered defining PATH variables in your environments (test, prod, etc.) and then injecting it in the properties file? For example: defaultZone: ${DEFAULT_ZONE}

Comment: Actually @Boris I want to add the line itself with placeholders like defaultZone: ${SomeEnv}.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36710661/9230755).

You should install [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and instead `${property.key}` use `@property.key@`. Like this:

```
us-west-2a: @eureka.environment@
```

Comment: Actually Artiow , i want to add this particular line itself. `defaultZone: dummy-url-1,dummy-url-2` or to be more clear I want to add the line with placeholder  like `defaultZone: @eureka.environment@`

Comment: Eventually, I am using maven resource plugin to resolve the placeholders but before that I need to add a line `defaultZone: @eureka.environment@` and then I am resolving the placeholder.

Comment: @Piyush Kumar, you may try to add maven property `<eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone>dummy-url-1,dummy-url-2</...>` or use JVM argument `-Deureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=dummy-url-1,dummy-url-2`. You might need [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/).