# Spring appliaction.properties doesn't load value from pom.xml file

Tags: spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I want to load data from the pom.xml file using application.properties and then load this value using @Value in a specific class.

So in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <takeScreenshots>true</takeScreenshots>
</properties>
```

Then in application.properties:

```
selenium.screenshotOnFailure=${takeScreenshots}
```

And then specific class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PropertiesContext {

@Value("${selenium.screenshotOnFailure}")
private String screenshotOnFailure;

@Bean("screenshotOnFailure")
public boolean takeScreenshotOnFailure() {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(screenshotOnFailure);
}
```

But it doesn't work.
During runtime I see that program return 
String `${selenium.screenshotOnFailure}` 
instead of boolean.
It seems the program doesn't load value from pom.xml.
What should I do?

Comment: this answer should be work https://stackoverflow.com/a/36710661/8112217

Comment: Thx so much! It works!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for a similar question that maybe could help,

The question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703499/using-maven-properties-in-application-properties-in-spring-boot)

The answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36710661/2706056)

Regards!