# -Djasypt.encryptor.password maven's option doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jasypt

I have an application with encrypted password for database connection, but when I want to run it with the secret key in maven options it doesn't work. I have added the jasypt plugin in the pom.xml.

The command I run:

```
mvn -Djasypt.encryptor.password=foo spring-boot:run
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ENC(Hu76tW6HJjEp730PNXSFOQ==)

jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

---

When I provide the secret key in the application.properties file, it does work.

The command I run when the secret key is provided:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

application.properties when the secret key is provided:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ENC(Hu76tW6HJjEp730PNXSFOQ==)

jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
jasypt.encryptor.password=foo
```

---

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        ...
        <jasypt.version>3.0.4</jasypt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String:

    Reason: either 'jasypt.encryptor.password', one of ['jasypt.encryptor.private-key-string', 'jasypt.encryptor.private-key-location'] for asymmetric encryption, or one of ['jasypt.encryptor.gcm-secret-key-string', 'jasypt.encryptor.gcm-secret-key-location', 'jasypt.encryptor.gcm-secret-key-password'] for AES/GCM encryption must be provided for Password-based or Asymmetric encryption

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Using Maven properties in application.properties in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703499/using-maven-properties-in-application-properties-in-spring-boot), you can add the property in `application.properties` as

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=@jasypt.encryptor.password@
```

And add below in pom.xml

```xml
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
   ...
   </build>
```

Then run

```
clean -Djasypt.encryptor.password=foo spring-boot:run
```

What this does is replace `@jasypt.encryptor.password@` by `foo` in `application.properties` inside your target folder.

Answer (score 0):

The "-D" options you are passing are actually passed to the maven process.

I think what you are looking for is the run goal parameters needed to pass to the JVM launching the spring-boot process.

Try this reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.run-goal.parameter-details.jvm-arguments