# How to property file value in Spring boot config class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to use a application.properties file in Config class

## application.properties

datasource.username=test

Config.class

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "abcFactory", 
    transactionManagerRef = "abcmanager",
    basePackages = { "com.emp.repository" }) 

    public class EmpConfig {
    
        @Value("${datasource.username}")
        String username;
        
        @Bean(name = "empDataSource")      
        public DataSource empDataSource(String url, String userName, String pwd) {        
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("XXX");
         dataSource.setUrl(url);
         dataSource.setUsername(userName);
         dataSource.setPassword(pwd);         
         return dataSource;        
 
        }
    
    
    }
```

How can i pass the property in to the username set field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you initialized your app, but normally you would put something like

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

Make sure you have one of these in your configs

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Then you can access values like this

```
@Value("${datasource.username}")
@NotNull //optional
String username;
```

Comment: you wouldn't need `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` since `@SpringBootApplication` already has the first two incorporated. `application.properties` is scanned for properties by default so you don't need to add it as a property source. And if you have spring boot starter in your pom you wouldn't need `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` either.

Comment: if i am using the  following, it is not working.                                                @Value("${datasource.username}")
@NotNull //optional
String username;

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635163/spring-boot-externalizing-properties-not-working/36635367#36635367 you can find an example of a working Spring Boot project with both internal and external properties. @RahulSharma is correct in all his comments.

Comment: @Mukti you need to add the code for us to see what's happening

Comment: @RahulSharma, i have updated the code above, still getting on @Value("${datasource.username}")