# How to externalize configuration in Spring Boot using profiles?

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, spring-boot, supervisord

I have an application where I would like to change a datasource password that is stored in a application.yml file. The password in the YML file is stored such as this:

```
----
spring:
    profiles: production
datasource:
    password: prodpassword
```

Note: I also have profiles for development and stage.

The password prop is set on a class using `ConfigurationProperties` such as follows:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource")
public class DataSourceConnector {

    private password;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Now, I try to override the prodpassword with prodpa$$word via a command line arg but it doesn't work:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar /usr/share/myapp/myapp-1.0.jar --datasource.password='prodpa$$word'
```

I also tried creating an identical (except the new password) application.yml file outside of the jar. That doesn't work either.

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar /usr/share/myapp/myapp-1.0.jar --spring.config.location=/usr/share/myapp/
```

Note: I left out the file name in the location param due to this note from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties:

> If you have specified any files in spring.config.location, profile-specific variants of those files will not be considered. Use directories in`spring.config.location` if you also want to also use profile-specific properties.

How can I override datasource.password within the application.yml of the jar?

Edit:
The application is being started / stopped using `supervisorctl`.

Comment: Have you tried `-Dspring.config.location=/usr/share/myapp/`?

Comment: You can view my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635163/spring-boot-externalizing-properties-not-working/36635367#36635367

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it did not work. It turns out that issue was unrelated to Spring. It was due to the way that I was running the application. The application runner (supervisorctl) was caching my config file (between application starts and stops). Sorry I did not include that in my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the config file that contains the `java` command, `supervisorctl` must reread the change:

```
supervisorctl reread
```

Next, activate the changes with:

```
supervisorctl update
```